# How can I exit from a goroutine (from within) from anywhere on the stack?

Tags: go, goroutine

For example:

```
func foo() {
    // How can I exit the goroutine here?
}

func bar() {
    foo()
}

func goroutine() {
    for {
        bar()
    }
}

func main() {
    go goroutine()
}
```

How can I exit the goroutine directly from `foo()` or `bar()`? I was thinking of maybe using `panic` and `recover`, but I am not sure exactly how they work. (With traditional exception handling, I would just wrap the body of `goroutine()` in a `try` block and throw an exception when I want to exit.)

EDIT: If I used `panic`, do I even need to `recover()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a function in runtime for exiting a goroutine: http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Goexit

```
runtime.Goexit()
```

---

If your panic escapes the goroutine, the entire program panics. So yes, you would need to recover.